# Why is it "Asian American" but "British Asian"?

Tags: adjectives

Is there any logic to the order? Or is it just some arbitrary historical accident?

Comment: If you look on Wikipedia, the OED, or Google you'll find extensive histories of such terms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The words "Asian" and "American" can be adjectives or nouns, in other words it makes sense to speak of an Asian, or an American, or of an American citizen, or an Asian visitor. The word "British" can be used as an adjective but it cannot be used as a noun; the noun form is "Briton".

The phrases "Asian American" and "American Asian"  are both correct; one is an American who is described as Asian, and the other is an Asian who is described as American. Likewise "British Asian" and "Asian Briton" are correct. "Asian British" has no noun, so it is incorrect.

Comment: But a 'British Asian' would (you say 'likewise') then be expected to be an Asian who has connections with Britain. But they're defined as British citizens.

Comment: Asian by ancestry (probably), but with British citizenship. That’s a pretty strong connection. Why not Asian Briton? Being from Australia I don’t know with certainty, but in Australia the word “Briton” is quite rarely used.

Comment: Outside 'Ancient Briton', I'd say it's rarer than 'pommie' in the UK. But the point is that [X][Y] where Y is the head noun and X is the premodifier, whether adjective or attributive noun, does not always mean 'a Y that is X'. Often, yes, but with many exceptions. And when we get to compounds ... a 'sergeant major' is far from being a major, for instance.

Comment: Indeed. I think though that the normal pattern is like "Asian American" - A Greek Australian is an Australian with Greek ancestry rather an Australian who is a citizen of Greece. This pattern can't be used with "British" because it is not a noun. The other aspect of "British" is the notion of "British subject", which has had different meanings over time.